# Picking spots in a string

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

- Find the number of $50$-digit combinations from $[9] = \{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$ in which each digit occurs at least two times.

Fill in the $10$ places with every element from $[9].$ This reduces the problem to finding the number $50$-digit combinations from $[9]$ in which each digit occurs at least once. This is a standard problem with standard solution. So, the answer is $\binom{k-1}{n-1} = \binom{40 - 1}{10 - 1} = \binom{39}{9}.$

How does this problem change if we choose $20$ spots first? I'd say we could select $30$ spots in $10^{30}$ ways. What goes wrong there? How can we fix this if we insist on filling in the $20$ places first?

Comment: This seems like a bad approach.  You will over count (if $1$, say, is used six times how do you know which of those six were the pre-assigned cases?).  I would go by Inclusion-Exclusion.  Subtract those in which one specified number appears too few times, then add those in which two specified numbers appear too few times, and so on.

Comment: @lulu, can you please elaborate why it matters we know which $1$s are pre-assigned? Isn't it enough that there are at least two $1$s in a string?

Comment: Sure...reduce the problem so that I am only putting $a,b$ into three slots but insist that both be used.  If you start by assigning a slot for $a$ then I count the case $aba$ twice.  Once assuming I first assigned the first slot to $a$ and then again assuming I first assigned the third slot to $a$.

Comment: To extend that example:  Inclusion-Exclusion tells us that the answer to my $a,b$ example is $2^3-2$.  this is easily verified by inspection.  Can you recover that answer using your method?

Comment: See if I understand you correctly. You're saying we can preselect first $20$ digits of a string to be $0123456789 \ 0123456789$ and choose the last $10$ digits to be $0123456789$ while also having a string where the first $10$ digits are chosen to be $0123456789$ and the last $20$ digits are preselected to be $0123456789 \ 0123456789$. If both of these strings have $0123456789 \ 0123456789$ in other $20$ places, then we have counted this string twice. By inclusion-exclusion our answer should be $10^{30} - $ union of all the redundant cases. How do we find these bad cases? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you've got the problem.  Inclusion exclusion goes by layers.  First remove the cases in which one specified digit occurs too seldom.  Say $1$ appears fewer than $2$ times...there are $9^{50}$ cases in which $1$ does not appear at all, at $50\times 9^{49}$ cases in which it appears exactly once.  We multiply by $10$ because there are $10$ digits I could have specified.  Thus the first subtraction is $10\times \left(9^{50}+50\times 9^{49}\right)$.  Now do the same for two specified numbers that appear fewer than $2$ times.  Then do three specified numbers and so on.  Tedious, but it works.

Comment: There are recursive methods that will work too, but I doubt they are easier.  There are too many states to keep track of...the final calculation will go quickly, but setting up the recursion will be very tedious.

Comment: To do it recursively:  Let $S(n,a,b,c)$ denote the number of strings of length $n$ such that exactly $a$ digits appear at least twice, exactly $b$ digits appear exactly once and exactly $c$ digits don't appear at all.   Then it is fairly easy to express $S(n,a,b,c)$ in terms of $S(n-1,a',b',c')$ where $a'≤a,b'≤b,c'≤c$.  Then iterate.  A machine could do this quickly.  i think Inclusion-Exclusion is easier if you intend to do it by hand.

Comment: @lulu, thank you for you help. A lot to digest here :)

Comment: No problem.  Good luck.  Note:  I got the inequalities wrong in my last comment.  All you have is that $a'≤a$.  The others can go down by $1$.

Comment: I forgot to ask. When we pre-select spots for ten digits from $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, 9\}$, shouldn't that be done in $\frac{50!}{40!}$ ways, that is, there are $50$ spots for $0$, $49$ spots for $1$, $48$ spots for $2$ etc?

Comment: As I said, I don't see anyway to do it using the preselecting method.