# Solving counting problems by way of recursion (need recommendations)

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, soft-question, recursion

While browsing around MSE I came across counting problems where some users recommend to use recursion to solve the problems. For example, in the following thread the user @lulu says that the problem at hand can be solved using recursion.

[Picking spots in a string](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279301/picking-spots-in-a-string)

The other day someone suggested recursion as well when I was struggling with a fairly straightforward counting problem. As we haven't covered recursion yet (not sure we will), I was wondering where I can learn more about solving counting problems with recursion. Any particular websites, books or lecture notes? Thanks.

Comment: *Concrete math* of Graham and Knuth and *Generatingfunctionology* of Wilf are good books about the matter, at least some chapters. For the second, by example, is interesting to learn how define recursion from generating functions, and viceversa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a textbook, [Problem solving strategies by Arthur Engel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982191) has a chapter on enumerative combinatorics which has some good examples of solving problems using recursion. It also has a lot of interesting exercises.